# How to copy new data in Googlesheet in the same sequence

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two googlesheets, In one google sheet (let's call it A) I am uploading the data using R cron and in another sheet (let's call it B) I'm importing the data from A using importrange formula.

In B, I am importing the data in sheet1 but I want to automatically copy the data from Sheet1 in Sheet2 whenever the Sheet1 gets updated. Also, I want to ensure that the new updated data gets append in Sheet2 without changing the sequence of previous records.

For Example,

If in B, Sheet1 has 5 records as mentioned below then copy it in new tab as Sheet2 and if in Sheet1 new data gets upload (suppose now there are 10 records in sheet1) then new uploaded five records should get appended in Sheet2 without changing the sequence and anything updated against records 1-5.

```
ID      Name       Date
1       ABC        2020-01-01
2       ART        2020-01-02
3       XUZ        2020-01-03
4       AFI        2020-01-03
5       SSR        2020-01-02
```

Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY5dvlrEf39ul7sqmzyBI1Hwoplh9_7eNGveeVfUQZA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sophia, I suggest you read this question/answer,   https://support.google.com/docs/thread/82615687?hl=en    ,since it addresses your issue.  You want formulas to provide dynamic data, that can change, and you also want to add manual data BESIDE the changing data.  There are ways to do this, but they may involve some redesign of your worksheet.  I'll see if I can put an example together...   QUESTION:  Are the ID values for each row of data always unique?

Comment: Here is another very similar question: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/22982787?hl=en  This includes a sample sheet, in the very last response, designed to show how to address the problem.  This involves using an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a tab, Sheet2-GK, to your sheet. This demonstrates using the ID value as an index in Sheet2, to allow manual data to be entered alongside dynamic data, which is updated from Sheet1 by formula.

The key formula, in Sheet2!B2, would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A6,Sheet1!A$1:C,{2,3},0))
```

Without more sample data, I can't test the results, but let me know if this works for you, as you add fresh data to Sheet1.